# Python Recursive Function Problem - Local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: function, recursion

Lets say I have an array `X` as follows:

0    34701

1    34705

2    34705

3    34711

4    34711

...

```
def batch(j):
    if X[j] != X[j+1]:
        X_j = X[0:j+2]
    
    else:
        loop(j+1)
    
    return X_j
```

batch(1) should return X[0:4], i.e. 34701, 34705, 34705, 34711, but why does this return "local variable 'X_j' referenced before assignment"?

Appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your only assignment to X_j is within an `if` block, and may not be reached before the function returns. The error is telling you that there are instances where X_j is being referenced by the return before it's ever assigned. Declare it (or better, initialize it) at the top of the function before trying to return it:

```py
def batch(j):
    X_j = 0
    if X[j] != X[j+1]:
        X_j = X[0:j+2]
    
    else:
        loop(j+1)
    
    return X_j
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response -- so I completely understand now thanks to you why you need to initialise with something (otherwise if you go straight to "else", X_j isn't defined and therefore error). However, if I initialise at 0, the result will be 0 for batch[1], for example, and not the array that I would expect.  Is there a different initialisation I should be using? Thanks again